# override update function in serializer

Tags: python, django

I am trying to override the update method in my serializer in order to update the field 'status' which is a column in my database.

I found here on StackOverflow this code, that will supposedly do the job for me:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    fields=instance._meta.fields
    exclude=[]
    for field in fields:
        field=field.name.split('.')[-1] #to get coulmn name
        if field in exclude:
            continue
        exec("instance.%s = validated_data.get(field, instance.%s)"%(field,field))
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

But I just do not understand what this line of code does?

```
exec("instance.%s = validated_data.get(field, instance.%s)"%(field,field))
```

I would appreciate some help, please.

EDIT:
this is the relevant part of my serializer:
(the update method is not defined but I define one in my view)

```
class Meta:
    model = Match
    fields = ['id', 'home_team', 'away_team', 'date_time', 'home_team_kit', 'away_team_kit',
              'home_team_score', 'away_team_score', 'competition_edition', 'competition_round',
              'stadium', 'pitch_length', 'pitch_width', 'referees', 'players', 'ball',
              'event_provider', 'lineup_provider', 'sr_id', 'status']

class MatchUpdateSerializer(MatchWriteSerializer):

    def get_unique_together_validators(self):
        return []
```

Comment: Can you share your serializer and if it's a modelserializer, your model too?

Comment: okay @Higor I'm going to update my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation

> This function supports dynamic execution of Python code, object must be either a string or a code object. If it is a string, the string is parsed as a suite of Python statements which is then executed (unless a syntax error occurs).

It means we can pass (valid) python code to exec function as string and it will execute it as normal python.

In your case, this function is getting data based on field name from validated data and assigning it to instance.

For example if there is a field `x` and we substitute it in string, resulting code will be

```
instance.x = validated_data.get(field, instance.x)
```

And this code will be executed by `exec` assigning value of x from validated data to instance.

Comment: Thank you @Nafees that was helpful